# Is subclassing NSNotification the right route if I want to add typed properties?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, inheritance, nsnotification, class-cluster

I am trying to subclass `NSNotification`.

Apple's docs for `NSNotification`state the following:

> `NSNotification` is a class cluster with no instance variables. As such,
>   you must subclass `NSNotification` and override the primitive methods
>   `name`, `object`, and `userInfo`. You can choose any designated initializer
>   you like, but be sure that your initializer does not call
>   `NSNotification`’s implementation of `init` (via `[super init]`).
>   `NSNotification` is not meant to be instantiated directly, and its `init`
>   method raises an exception.

But this isn't clear to me. Should I create an initializer like this?

```
-(id)initWithObject:(id)object
{
    return self;
}
```

Comment: It is *highly* unusual to create a subclass of `NSNotification`. Can you explain why you feel the need to do this?

Comment: I want to use NSNotifications with strongly typed properties rather than using the generic userInfo object. I also like the fact that a subclassed notification better encapsulates its purpose. I would prefer [UserPrefsChangedNotification alloc] init] to passing a name string to an NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: you could use an `NSNotification` category to add some properties, and then have the method implementations attach stuff to the `NSNotification` using associated objects. The category could even have a convenience constructor for you.

Comment: I'm still wrapping my brain around Objective C and my instinct is to subclass, but that does make a lot of sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DaveDeLong Am I missing something? It seems it is not possible to add properties in categories.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Subclassing `NSNotification` is an atypical operation.  I think I've only seen it done once or twice in the past few years.

If you're looking to pass things along with the notification, that's what the `userInfo` property is for.  If you don't like accessing things through the `userInfo` directly, you could use a category to simplify access:

```
@interface NSNotification (EasyAccess)

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *foo;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNumber *bar;

@end

@implementation NSNotification (EasyAccess)

- (NSString *)foo {
  return [[self userInfo] objectForKey:@"foo"];
}

- (NSNumber *)bar {
  return [[self userInfo] objectForKey:@"bar"];
}

@end
```

You can also use this approach to simplify `NSNotification` creation.  For example, your category could also include:

```
+ (id)myNotificationWithFoo:(NSString *)foo bar:(NSString *)bar object:(id)object {
  NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsForKeys:foo, @"foo", bar, @"bar", nil];
  return [self notificationWithName:@"MyNotification" object:object userInfo:d];
}
```

If, for some strange reason, you'd need the properties to be mutable, then you'd need to use [associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) to accomplish that:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
static const char FooKey;
static const char BarKey;

...

- (NSString *)foo {
  return (NSString *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &FooKey);
}

- (void)setFoo:(NSString *)foo {
  objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &FooKey, foo, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

- (NSNumber *)bar {
  return (NSNumber *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &BarKey);
}

- (void)setBar:(NSNumber *)bar {
  objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &BarKey, bar, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

...
```

Comment: Great explaination. Thanks a lot

Comment: On further reflection this doesn't really solve the problem I have. Adding categories is fine if I want all instances of NSNotification to gain this extra functionality, but I want the option to have different specialised notifications. Perhaps one will be carrying a payload of type NSArray, whilst another might be carrying a Some Class as its payload. I understand that I can use userInfo as a kind of generic dump for the data a notification carries, but I think its much cleaner to have a notification specialise.

Comment: This is a great solution for this problem. You can make a different category for each "special" notification you want.

Comment: Good explanation of using a category; this is a good solution in most cases. But, I don't understand the implied aversion to sub-classing NSNotification.  It doesn't strike me as being a bad practice - Apple even discuss doing it - and should yield better performance than looking up all 'fields' from the userInfo dictionary, in performance critical code.  I'm using an NSNotification subclass for this reason in my current project.  Dave DeLong, did you have any other specific reasons not to take this approach?

Answer (score 2):

It seems this does work. For example:

```
#import "TestNotification.h"

NSString *const TEST_NOTIFICATION_NAME = @"TestNotification";

@implementation TestNotification

-(id)initWithObject:(id)object
{
    object_ = object;
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)name
{
    return TEST_NOTIFICATION_NAME;
}

-(id)object
{
    return object_;
}

- (NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

also beware a massive Gotcha related to NSNotifications. The type of NSNotifications greated using *NSNotification notificationWithName:object:* is NSConcreteNotification, not NSNotification. And to make it a little more awkward, if you are checking for class, NSConcreteNotification is private so you have nothing to compare to.

Comment: With class clusters you should expect to get anything back that is documented and sometimes that anything is literally anything that replies YES to isKindOf

Answer (score 1):

You don’t set it, exactly—you just override the implementation of the `name` method so it returns what you want. In other words:

```
- (NSString *)name
{
    return @"Something";
}
```

Your initializer looks fine—I haven’t seen an example of an `init` that doesn’t call its superclass’s implementation before, but if that’s what the doc’s saying you should do, it’s probably worth a try.

Comment: yep. I realised I should override and return the desired value about a second after I posted this, but you must have got in there before I edited it out. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `userInfo` argument when delivering a notification. Why not create a payload and send that.

```
// New file:

@interface NotificationPayload : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *thing;
@end

@implementation NotificationPayload
@end

// Somewhere posting:

NotificationPayload *obj = [NotificationPayload new];
obj.thing = @"LOL";

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Hi" object:whatever userInfo:@{ @"payload": obj }];

// In some observer:

- (void)somethingHappened:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  NotificationPayload *obj = notification.userInfo[@"payload"];
  NSLog(@"%@", obj.thing);
}
```

Done.

As a side note: I've found over the years that making a conscious effort to avoid subclassing has made my code more clean, maintainable, changeable, testable and extensible. If you can solve the problem using protocols or categories then you wont lock yourself into the first shoddy design you come up with. With Swift 2.0 protocol extensions in the mix we're really laughing too.