# Inherit from NSNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, inheritance, class-cluster

I want to create a subclass of `NSNotification`. **I don't want to create a category or anything else.**

As you may know `NSNotification` is a **Class Cluster**, like `NSArray` or `NSString`.

I'm aware that a subclass of a cluster class needs to:

- Declare its own storage
- Override all initializer methods of the superclass
- Override the superclass’s primitive methods (described below)

This is my subclass (nothing fancy):

```
@interface MYNotification : NSNotification
@end

@implementation MYNotification

- (NSString *)name { return nil; }

- (id)object { return nil; }

- (NSDictionary *)userInfo { return nil; }

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name object:(id)object userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    return self = [super initWithName:name object:object userInfo:userInfo];
}
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    return self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
}

@end
```

When I use it, I get an extraordinary:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** initialization method -initWithName:object:userInfo: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class MYNotification: Create a concrete instance!'
```

What else do I have to do in order to inherit from `NSNotification`?

Comment: Don't call the superclass initialiser -For example - see the answers to [Is subclassing NSNotification the right route if I want to add typed properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572059/is-subclassing-nsnotification-the-right-route-if-i-want-to-add-typed-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that was trying to call the superclass initialiser. You can't do that because is an abstract class. So, in the initializer you just have to init your storage.

Because this is horrible, I end up creating a category for `NSNotification` instead. There I added three kind methods:

- Static constructor for my custom notification: Here I configure `userInfo` to be used as the storage.
- Method to add information to the storage: The notification observer will call this to update `userInfo`.
- Method to process the information submitted by the observes: After the post method has finished, the notification has collected all the information needed. We just have to process it and return it. This is optional if you are not interested in collecting data.

In the end, the category it's just a helper to deal with `userInfo`.

Thanks [@Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) for your comment!